# Iterate through each rows list properties

Tags: c#

I currently have the below piece of code:

```
public string ReplaceData(List<ListData> list, string emailBody)
{

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        emailBody = emailBody.Replace("<Item1>", list.FirstOrDefault().Item1);
        emailBody = emailBody.Replace("<Item2>", list.FirstOrDefault().Item2);
        emailBody = emailBody.Replace("<Item3>", list.FirstOrDefault().Item3);
        emailBody = emailBody.Replace("<Item4>", list.FirstOrDefault().Item4);
        emailBody = emailBody.Replace("<Item5>", list.FirstOrDefault().Item5);
        emailBody = emailBody.Replace("<Item6>", list.FirstOrDefault().Item6);
    }

    ...
}
```

Instead of repeating the above replace each time, is it possible to iterate through each rows properties of the list, obtaining both each property name and value, so only one replace is required as it will instead loop through each rows properties one by one rather than each row with all its containing properties?

I have never done this before so I can provide additional information if required. This needs to be as efficient as possible as on average I will have around 15,000 rows of data to iterate through so reflection might not be the most efficient method to achieve what I want.

The current list will need to change from this:

Row1 
Item1 Name Item 1 value, 
Item2 Name Item 2 value, 
Item3 Name Item 3 value

To this:

Row1 
Item1 Name Item 1 value 
Row2 
Item2 Name Item 2 value 
Row3 
Item3 Name Item 3 value

Comment: I assume you mean to access the properties of `item`, rather than the first entry in the `list` each iteration?

Comment: Yes thats what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this (using reflection):

```
 public string ReplaceData(List<ListData> list, string emailBody)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {           
            foreach (var property in item.GetType().GetProperties())
            {                 
                string stringToReplace = string.Format("<{0}>", property.Name.ToString());
                string valueToReplaceWith = property.GetValue(item, null).ToString();
                emailBody = emailBody.Replace(stringToReplace, valueToReplaceWith);
            }               
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to refer Property by its name, you can do it only by reflection. Because you have 6 properties for each item in your list -(Item1,Item2,...Item6).

Alternatively you can use parallel foreach which might fasten up

```
Parallel.ForEach(list,(item) =>
{
    emailBody = emailBody.Replace("<Item1>", list.FirstOrDefault().Item1);
    emailBody = emailBody.Replace("<Item2>", list.FirstOrDefault().Item2);
    emailBody = emailBody.Replace("<Item3>", list.FirstOrDefault().Item3);
    emailBody = emailBody.Replace("<Item4>", list.FirstOrDefault().Item4);
    emailBody = emailBody.Replace("<Item5>", list.FirstOrDefault().Item5);
    emailBody = emailBody.Replace("<Item6>", list.FirstOrDefault().Item6);
});
```